# Python: replace nth word in string

Tags: python

What is the easiest way in Python to replace the nth word in a string, assuming each word is separated by a space?
For example, if I want to replace the tenth word of a string and get the resulting string.

Comment: Try to include a sample input and expected output, plus share your effort to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you may do something like this:

```
nreplace=1
my_string="hello my friend"
words=my_string.split(" ")
words[nreplace]="your"
" ".join(words)
```

Here is another way of doing the replacement:

```
nreplace=1
words=my_string.split(" ")
" ".join([words[word_index] if word_index != nreplace else "your" for word_index in range(len(words))])
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your string is:

```
my_string = "This is my test string."
```

You can split the string up using `split(' ')`

```
my_list = my_string.split()
```

Which will set `my_list` to

```
['This', 'is', 'my', 'test', 'string.']
```

You can replace the 4th list item using

```
my_list[3] = "new"
```

And then put it back together with

```
my_new_string = " ".join(my_list)
```

Giving you

```
"This is my new string."
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution involving list comprehension:

```
text = "To be or not to be, that is the question"
replace = 6
replacement = 'it'
print ' '.join([x if index != replace else replacement for index,x in enumerate(s.split())])
```

The above produces:

```
To be or not to be, it is the question
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a generator expression and the string `join()` method:

```
my_string = "hello my friend"
nth = 0
new_word = 'goodbye'

print(' '.join(word if i != nth else new_word
                for i, word in enumerate(my_string.split(' '))))
```

Output:

```
goodbye my friend
```

Answer (score 0):

Through re.sub.

```
>>> import re
>>> my_string = "hello my friend"
>>> new_word = 'goodbye'
>>> re.sub(r'^(\s*(?:\S+\s+){0})\S+', r'\1'+new_word, my_string)
'goodbye my friend'
>>> re.sub(r'^(\s*(?:\S+\s+){1})\S+', r'\1'+new_word, my_string)
'hello goodbye friend'
>>> re.sub(r'^(\s*(?:\S+\s+){2})\S+', r'\1'+new_word, my_string)
'hello my goodbye'
```

Just replace the number within curly braces with the position of the word you want to replace - 1. ie, for to replace the first word, the number would be `0`, for second word the number would be 1, likewise it goes on.